# Scrolling navigation bar loses some formatting when in a fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to learn how to do a scrolling navigation bar. It appears I have the scrolling part nailed down, but, for some reason, the left offset seems to change once the navigation bar is set to fixed. Originally, the bar would snap to the left. Setting the containing div's width to 100% makes the bar more centered, but it's still off. Furthermore, I can't seem to get centering the buttons right.

```js
// Javascript

window.onload = function() {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var navbarY = navbar.offsetTop;

  window.onscroll = function() {

    if (window.scrollY >= navbarY) {
      navbar.style.position = "fixed";
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    } else if (window.scrollY < navbarY) {
      navbar.style.position = "static";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
/***CSS***/

/*HEADER*/

#header {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 200px 0 200px;
}
/*NAVIGATION BAR*/

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar ul {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 200px 0 200px;
  position: static;
  top: auto;
}
#navbar ul li {
  margin: 0;
}
#navbar ul li a {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  font: bold 1em Arial, san-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font: bold 1em Arial, san-serif;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*CONTAINER*/

#container {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 200px 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Test.css" />
  <script src="Test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">

  </div>
  <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Margin auto break your code, remove it and fix real margin

Comment: it s strange but apparently fixed element margin is based on <html> and not on <body> and on chrome body have 8px margin

Comment: I edited my code to reflect changes to margins. This improves the formatting some, but there still appears to be padding to the right side of the bar.

Comment: Oh. I added `body {margin: 0;}` to my CSS fixing the right side of the bar. Thanks!